# Django InlineModelAdmin gives error 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

From models.py

```
class Indicator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    youtube = models.CharField(max_length=LONG_BLOG_POST_CHAR_LEN)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=LONG_BLOG_POST_CHAR_LEN)    
    recommendation = models.CharField(max_length=LONG_BLOG_POST_CHAR_LEN)
    isPublic = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    methods_path = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='')
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name   

class IndicatorParameterInt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    indicator_int_parameter = models.ForeignKey(Indicator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class IndicatorParameterFloat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    setting = models.FloatField(default=1)
    indicator_float_parameter = models.ForeignKey(Indicator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Comparison(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

From admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register( MarketData )
admin.site.register( Indicator )
admin.site.register( UserProfile )



class IndicatorParameterIntInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IndicatorParameterInt
    fk_name = "indicator_int_parameter"

class IndicatorParameterFloatInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IndicatorParameterFloat
    fk_name = "indicator_float_parameter"   

class ComparisonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comparison
    fk_name = "Comparison"  

class IndicatorInline(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ 
                IndicatorParameterIntInline,
                IndicatorParameterFloatInline,
                ComparisonInline, 
              ]

admin.site.unregister( Indicator )
admin.site.register( IndicatorInline )
```

The error **TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable** comes up on the final line of admin: admin.site.register( IndicatorInline ). It doesn't matter if I try to register IndicatorInline first or any of the foreign key classes.

I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598524/django-admin-inline-model-for-user), which encouraged using the fk_name attribute. The error occurs regardless of whether or not I use fk_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, try not to use `import *` - always import the model that you are using.

Next, I think changing this should be enough

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *





class IndicatorParameterIntInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IndicatorParameterInt
    fk_name = "indicator_int_parameter"

class IndicatorParameterFloatInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IndicatorParameterFloat
    fk_name = "indicator_float_parameter"   

class ComparisonInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comparison
    fk_name = "Comparison"  

class IndicatorInline(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ 
                IndicatorParameterIntInline,
                IndicatorParameterFloatInline,
                ComparisonInline, 
              ]

admin.site.register(Indicator, IndicatorInline)
admin.site.register(MarketData, )
admin.site.register(UserProfile, )
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is registering the model and inline class together the only way to make it happy?

Comment: You always have to register your model with your admin model. This is how you tell your django admin that it has to use this specific ModelAdmin. Because as you can see, you have no information about model in your IndicatorInline.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the model when you register the model admin class.

```
admin.site.register(Indicator, IndicatorInline)
```

Note that if you remove `admin.site.register( Indicator )` from the top of the module, then you won't have to call `admin.site.unregister(Indicator)` later.

I would suggest renaming `IndicatorInline` - it's a model admin that has inlines, so it would be better to name it `IndicatorAdmin`. In that case, you would register it with:

```
admin.site.register(Indicator, IndicatorAdmin)
```

Comment: @surfer190 I'm not sure what you mean. This answer shouldn't conflict with the Django docs.