# Why do I get "TypeError: Meta defining class is not iterable" When using a readonly field in Django admin?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I defined my model as following:

```
from django.db import models

class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

The problem is that when I want to make the `author` field `readonly` in `admin.py` as following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import Books

class Books(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('author',)

admin.site.register(Books)
```

I get the following error upon running server:
[image]

Comment: Just search for the error message it good practice of investigation. In your case it will bring you directly to the answer of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41878607/1173647 (first result on google: "django TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different name for **model class** and **model admin class**

```
class BooksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # change the model admin class name
    readonly_fields = ('author',)


admin.site.register(Books, BooksAdmin)
```